# CellDingbat is below the first line of the Cell

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

According to the Documentation, "[Dingbats are placed to the left of the main contents of a cell, aligned with the first line of the contents.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellDingbat.html)" But when I evaluate

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["Text"], CellDingbat -> "CellDingbat"]
```

in a Notebook with the `"Default"` stylesheet I get

[image: screenshot]

One can see that the `CellDingbat` is placed lower than the first line of the `Cell`. Why this happens? Is there a way to align `CellDingbat` with the first line of the `Cell`?

Comment: Alexey: Why do you need to have `BoxData` wrapped around your cell contents? Are you actually putting the `CellDingbat` on an "Input" type cell or just on a formatted "Text" or "Section" type cell?

Comment: @Simon I use `CellDingbat` for `Cells` without predefined styles but with explicit set of options (the reason is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690659)). And `BoxData` is unavoidable because I generate formatted `Cell`s.

Comment: But can you use the construct `Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[...]]], CellDingbat->"dingbat"]` as shown in my new answer? (You don't need to use any predefined styles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you don't want the `CellDingbat` on a standard "Input" or "Code" cell style, then as pointed out by [Sjoerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589535/celldingbat-is-below-the-first-line-of-the-cell/7589760#7589760), the cell's contents and dingbat automatically align. It's only when you wrap the cell contents in `BoxData` that they become misaligned.

If the cell you want is a "Text" or "Section" (etc) cell, then you can still have formatted text provided the cell contents are contained in `TextData[...]`. For example

[image: dingBaT]

Note that I've started the text and ended the dingbat with a capital `T` so that the alignment is clear.

If you hand make your "Input" cells to have their contents wrapped in `TextData` (which does not happen by default) then the code will run, but the styling is not quite right. The spacing is wrong and syntax highlighting not active. Compare the following

[image: input]

The first printed cell has syntax highlighting but the cell dingbat is misaligned, while the second printed cell has no syntax highlighting and poor spacing, but the dingbat is perfectly aligned!

---

Finally, I should have realised that a solution like this would work, because I've been using cell dingbats for automatic section numbering for ages and have never had alignment problems.  E.g., here's the outline of a notebook I was working on last week that contains supporting code for a chapter in my thesis:
[image: WZ]
The section and subsection cells are given dingbats in the stylesheet, e.g.,
`CellDingbat->TextData[{CounterBox["Section"], ". "}]`.

Comment: Quick tests have showed that `Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[...]]], CellDingbat->"dingbat"]` works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the baseline of the dingbat and cell contents don't change in the same way when the cell contents are wrapped in `BoxData`. As [Sjoerd pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589535/celldingbat-is-below-the-first-line-of-the-cell/7589760#7589760), removing the `BoxData` from the cell contents makes things line up, but adding `BoxData` to the `CellDingbat` does not seem to change anything.

The baseline can be shifted using an `AdjustmentBox` and after playing around for a while, I found that the baseline is out by   `CurrentValue["FontAxisOffset"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]`.
Both of these terms change with the `Magnification` but it turns out that the observed offset is the constant value obtained when `Magnification->1`. In this case, the ratio is `0.20833 == 5/24`.

I'm not sure if the problem really is with the baseline and whether there is a good underlying reason for the behaviour. I'm also not sure why the required shift does not depend on the magnification of the Cell, Notebook or $FrontEnd. But it seems to work and I've spent enough time playing around with it!

So to test that everything is (basically) ok, try

```
Do[CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["TxyT"], 
      CellDingbat -> BoxData[AdjustmentBox["TxyT", BoxBaselineShift -> -5/24]], 
      Magnification -> mag], {mag, 1, 5}]
```

[image: dingbats]

And also test how

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["TxyT"], 
   CellDingbat -> BoxData[AdjustmentBox["TxyT", BoxBaselineShift -> -5/24]], 
   Magnification -> Inherited]
```

looks for various magnifications of the containing notebook and frontend, e.g.,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification -> 4.]
```

and/or

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Magnification -> 4.]
```

Comment: On my machine (*Mathematica* 7.0.1 under Windows XP) `BoxBaselineShift -> -4/24` gives the correct placement shown on your screenshot. Probably this value is version and OS-dependent.

Comment: It also depends on the font used: specifying different fonts for `CellDingbat` and `BoxData` breaks alignment again: ``Do[CellPrint@
  Cell[BoxData["TxyT"], 
   CellDingbat -> 
    BoxData[AdjustmentBox[StyleBox["TxyT", FontFamily -> "Times"], 
      BoxBaselineShift -> -4/24]], Magnification -> mag], {mag, 1, 5}]``:.

Comment: @Alexey: OK, I'm runnning Mma 8.0.1 in linux. Is the `CurrentValue["FontAxisOffset"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` ratio different on your machine? This should also change with the fonts, so maybe you should use `BoxBaselineShift -> Dynamic[-CurrentValue["FontAxisOffset"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]`, or something similar using the *obj* argument of [CurrentValue](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html)

Comment: `CurrentValue["FontAxisOffset"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` gives 25/99 but this value changes when I change Magnification. `Options[$FrontEnd, Magnification]` is set to `{Magnification -> 1.5}`. `BoxBaselineShift -> Dynamic[-CurrentValue["FontAxisOffset"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` does not give the correct placement.

Comment: @Alexey: Damn... I was hoping that this ratio would be the correct shift irrespective of system and setup. I guess that my guess (and hopes) were no good! Sorry...

Comment: Seemingly these things are still not implemented properly. You should not apologize. Thank you for your effort! I also thought of `\[AlignmentMarker]` but found no way to use it in this case.

Answer (score 3):

### CellLabel instead of CellDingbat

Dingbats are normally little icons, not text.  By design, they are positioned somewhat under the baseline of the contents of the first line of the cell.  To my eye, they look fine that way.

If you want a label for the cell, instead of a Dingbat, use `CellLabel`:

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["Text"], CellLabel -> "Example"]
```

---

[image: cell label]

You can handle the left allignment through `CellMargins`.

If you prefer the label on the left, have the cell formatted as `Output`, but notice that the alignment will depend on the screen magnification as the following 3 examples show:

---

[image: magnify 1]

---

[image: times one and one half]

---

[image: times 2]

---

Comment: By the way, did anyone notice that the black circle dingbat in the third example (200% magnification)  moved to an entirely new position, away from `In[29]:=`.  I only used the example to highlight `CellLabel`'s, but something weird happened to the dingbat of the input cell!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that if you replace `BoxData` with `TextData` (or remove `BoxData`, leaving "Text") the dingbat and the cell contents are aligned.

Comment: Unfortunately I need `BoxData` to be able to format the `Cell` contents.

Answer (score 1):

Does specifying the `CellBaseline` have any effect?

As in

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData["Text"], CellDingbat -> "CellDingbat", 
  CellBaseline -> Bottom]]
```

rather than the default `CellBaseline -> Baseline`

Comment: Actually, that seems to work perfectly! (I thought I had tried all the options of the form `"*Baseline*"`... oh well)

Comment: It does not work when different fonts are used: `CellPrint[Cell[BoxData["Text"],CellDingbat->StyleBox["CellDingbat",FontFamily->"Times"],CellBaseline->Bottom]]`.